# How can I prevent Visual Studio from adding Crystal Reports to the Toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have around 30-40 reports in my project, and Visual Studio 2008 insists on adding them to the Toolbox each and every time I launch Visual Studio and go to the Designer. As you can imagine, this takes a while and consumes time that I could be otherwise programming. I have other custom controls that I don't want to go away, but I don't need the reports displayed there at all. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into Tools --> Options Then find Windows Forms Designer General properties.  Then set the last entry AutoToolboxPopulate to False.

This will stop Visual Studio from loading your reports into the toolbox.

Comment: that gets rid of my other custom controls that I want to keep, how can I make them reappear?

Comment: you need to use the Choose Items menu and select them from the list.  Then you can select exactly which controls you want in the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible for your project, but don't use strongly typed reports. I've never had a use for them. Why do you need 30 of them? I've always stored the report path in a database and kept all my .rpt's out of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I've never seen this happen before. You may right click on the toolbox and click "Choose Items" to bring open the Toolbox items window. In there you can make sure that they aren't selected in the .NET Framework Components tab.

If they are lumped in with your user controls then I think you can change the namespace of either the reports or the user controls to separate them out, but I'm not 100% sure on that. Hope that helps if only marginally. :)

Comment: That will get rid of them until I restart Visual Studio, and then they'll come right back.